# CoreData entities to UITableView with sections

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, ios9

My data model is very simple, like a regular word dictionary:

[image]

The letters are the letters of the alphabet, the words are the words and definitions of the dictionary. My goal is to display the data in a UITableView with the Letter being the section and the words beneath.

My code:

```
 var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Letter")

    let letterSort =
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "letterName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [letterSort]

    fetchedResultsController =
        NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "letterName",
            cacheName: "dict")

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
 }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView
    (tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let sectionInfo =
        fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.name
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo =
        fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        print(sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

I learned this code from a tutorial. It seems to work. The section number equals 26, and each header is a through z.

The question is how do I get the number of rows in a section and how do I reference the data to put them in a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this code is going to do what you want.  Typically the `NSFetchRequest` that you use to construct the `NSFetchedResultsController` that populates a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` must fetch the entity type you actually want to display (or things become complicated).  Have you tried something like this?

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Word")

let letterSort =
NSSortDescriptor(key: "letter.letterName", ascending: true)
let wordSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "word", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [letterSort, wordSort]

fetchedResultsController =
    NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "letter.letterName",
        cacheName: "dict")

fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Assuming that your word values and associated letters are correct, I think this should do what you want.  It's also worth noting that the `cacheName` must be unique in your application, so you might want something more complex than simply `"dict"`.

Comment: This looks almost right, but you have to add a *first sort descriptor* corresponding to the sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: You don't explicitly have to if the sort ordering would not be affected.  Hence my assumption about word values and associated letters.  Your suggest would make it more correct however, I'll update the example.

Comment: That seems to work. How do you reference the data to display in the cell? (sorry a little new to this)

Comment: @lascoff: If you create a new "Master-Detail Application" in Xcode and activate the "Use Core Data" checkbox then you'll get sample code for all necessary methods for free ... :)

Comment: You would use the methods of `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the objects corresponding to the `indexPath` of the cell, then reference their attributes and set them to the labels or other outlets of your cell.  As @MartinR points out, there are certainly many tutorials about how to do this.